# why do i get PHP fatal error when i want to install an extension

Tags: php, yii2

```
$php composer.phar require "kartik-v/yii2-password": "@dev"
```

Error msg:

```
Call to undefined method Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks() in /home/john/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/VcsPackageFilter.php on line 272
```

When i wanna add an extension in my project i got this error, help me to solve it.

Comment: Using Linux or Windows?

Comment: i have used it in linux

Answer (score 23):

You should delete composer asset plugin :

- Linux : `rm -rf ~/.composer/vendor/fxp`
- Windows : `rm -r %APPDATA%\Composer\vendor\fxp`

And re-install it :

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

Read more : https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/pull/133

Comment: rm -rf ~/.composer/vendor/fxp/ &
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3" for me

Comment: For windows users the path is: `C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor`. Replace `[USER_NAME]` with your own username.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I had the same error with an old version (existing folder) of the plugin:

```
$ composer global update
```

or if the global update doesn't work, you can remove manually the global installation folder of this plugin in `C:\Users\$USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin` and reinstall the plugin by running the command:

$ composer global update

Answer (score 2):

Following Federico advice what I've done is the following

```
rm -rf /root/.composer/*
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
```

And now everything works fine.