# 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method' when I run composer update

Tags: php, composer-php

Following error occured when I try to run composer update or run any command:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks() in /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/VcsPackageFilter.php on line 272
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks() in /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/VcsPackageFilter.php on line 272

Comment: please add your composer code here.

Comment: As per the error it seems complete package or all required dependencies are not downloaded or loaded.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32901907/3647441

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to remove the invalid / incomplete version by using

`composer global remove fxp/composer-asset-plugin`

In case that fails, you might remove the plugin folder manually from Composers home folder:

`rm -rf ~/.composer/vendor/fxp`

Then, reinstall the plugin and cross fingers that everything works now :)

`composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"`